# How to make different threads execute in different logical CPU by using pthread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I found that when I use something like this:

```
pthread_t thread_1, thread_2;
pthread_create (&thread_1, NULL, (void *) function_1, NULL);
pthread_create (&thread_2, NULL, (void *) function_2, NULL);
```

Both of thread_1 and thread_2 are executed in the same logical CPU.

How to make both of them execute in different logical CPU?

Thanks.

Comment: They are both ready and are run on the same core even though another core is free?

Comment: @Martin James Yes. When other cores are free, both of them run in the same core. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` lets you set the CPU affinity mask of the thread to a CPU set.

**Example:**

```
int s, j;
cpu_set_t cpuset;
pthread_t thread;

thread = pthread_self();

/* Set affinity mask to include CPUs 0 to 7 */

CPU_ZERO(&cpuset); for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    CPU_SET(j, &cpuset);

s = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset); if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_setaffinity_np");
```

`pthread_getaffinity_np` returns the CPU affinity mask of a thread.

**Note:** This function is not portable.

Comment: My OS is windows NT, and compiler is gcc-mingw32. Can `pthread_getaffinity_np` be compiled successfully?

Comment: @user2967915 I guess not. On Windows, you have `SetThreadAffinityMask` and `SetProcessAffinityMask` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity#Specific_operating_systems)

Answer (score 0):

```
   int pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_t thread, size_t cpusetsize,
                              const cpu_set_t *cpuset);
   int pthread_getaffinity_np(pthread_t thread, size_t cpusetsize,
                              cpu_set_t *cpuset);
```

I think these function can help you. Read this document:
[enter link description here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)

Comment: My OS is windows NT, and compiler is gcc-mingw32. Can pthread_getaffinity_np be compiled successfully?

Comment: @user2967915 I think you cann't success.Becase these function are only in Linux system not in gcc. But you can try, have a good luck.